# firebase promise call in foreach with node firebase functions

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

On the firebase functions, I have next code:

```
app.post('/licence', (req, res) => {
    let { email, machine_id, product_id } = req.body
    let arr_product_ids = product_id.split(",").map(function (val) { return {product_id: val}; }); 
    let res_to_print = '';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        arr_product_ids.forEach(function(n){
            res_to_print = asyncGetLicences(n.product_id, email, machine_id)
            console.log('res_to_print')
            console.log(res_to_print)
        });

    }).then((state) => {
        console.log(state)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

I need to call query two times to firebase query! So I call it in foreach loop.

Here is the function that needs to be called twice:

```
function asyncGetLicences(product_id, email, machine_id) {
    licences_to_print = []

    db.collection('licences', 'desc').where('email', '==', email).where('product_id', '==', product_id).get()
    .then(data => {
        let licences = []
        data.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data().email);
            licences.push({
                id: doc.id,
                email: doc.data().email,
                product: doc.data().product,
                createdAt: doc.data().createdAt
            });
        });
        if(typeof this.licences !== 'undefined' && this.licences.length > 0){
            let string = email+machine_id+product_id+'55';
            let api = md5(string);
            let uppercase = api.toUpperCase()+'-';
            licences_to_print.push(uppercase);

            return licences_to_print
            //return res.send('"'+uppercase+'"');//res.json(this.licences);
        } else {
            return licences_to_print
            //return res.status(200).send('nothing to find');
        }

    })
}
```

I'm struggling with this simple promise...I had this in PHP and it was very easy, but node.js and firebase I got stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the promises in an array and insert into `Promise.all()` and then return this in the main function. This will collectively get the return from each promises asynchronously and return a single collective response.

```
app.post('/licence', (req, res) => {
let { email, machine_id, product_id } = req.body
let arr_product_ids = product_id.split(",").map(function (val) { return {product_id: val}; }); 
let res_to_print = '';

const promises = []  // Empty array
arr_product_ids.forEach(function(n){
    promises.push(asyncGetLicences(n.product_id, email, machine_id));
});

return Promise.all(promises).then(res_to_print => {
    console.log('res_to_print')
    console.log(res_to_print)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

The second function:

```
function asyncGetLicences(product_id, email, machine_id) {
licences_to_print = []

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
db.collection('licences', 'desc').where('email', '==', email).where('product_id', '==', product_id).get()
.then(data => {
    let licences = []
    data.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().email);
        licences.push({
            id: doc.id,
            email: doc.data().email,
            product: doc.data().product,
            createdAt: doc.data().createdAt
        });
    });
    if(typeof this.licences !== 'undefined' && this.licences.length > 0){
        let string = email+machine_id+product_id+'55';
        let api = md5(string);
        let uppercase = api.toUpperCase()+'-';
        licences_to_print.push(uppercase);

        resolve(licences_to_print)
        //return res.send('"'+uppercase+'"');//res.json(this.licences);
    } else {
        resolve(licences_to_print)
        //return res.status(200).send('nothing to find');
    }
}))
```

Comment: can you write it in codes? easier to get it for me :)